# Handling Rack Timeout exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the [Rack-timeout](https://github.com/heroku/rack-timeout) gem and a Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException occurs. I did no configuration outside of putting this gem into my gemfile.

How do I handle these exceptions so that they don't stop the normal app's procedure but instead just log and let me know about them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose of that gem is to raise exceptions after a timeout

> "Abort requests that are taking too long; an exception is raised."

If that's not what you want to do, perhaps you shouldn't be using that particular gem? Random google hit https://github.com/moove-it/rack-slow-log

Comment: I thought that the gem's purpose was to caught and raise exceptions so I can spot where long processes take place and so that I can handle them in a different manner. maybe I am mistaken?

Answer (score 4):

You can catch the exception in your application with

```
# in your app/controllers/application_controller.rb
rescue_from Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException do |exception|
  # do something
end
```

But as it's an exception I don't believe it's possible to return execution to where it was interrupted.

However, timeout also drops a log message every 1 second like this:

```
source=rack-timeout id=1123e70d486cbca9796077dc96279126 timeout=20000ms
service=1018ms state=active
```

Perhaps you could increase the interval of these to, say 5 seconds, and change the timeout to something high like 120 seconds, that way it's unlikely to actually interrupt anything, but you will get log messages to tell you that something is running long.

Answer (score 0):

to change the timeout, run

`export RACK_TIMEOUT_SERVICE_TIMEOUT=30`